# What is the final-column CSS Grid layout property and where is it documented?

Tags: css, css-grid

I was trying to think of a way to make a grid item span all columns. As I was doing this GitHub copilot suggested `final-column`. It works in Chrome, but I can't find it documented anywhere... I even searched [the Mozilla docs on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-end). for `final-column` but there aren't any results.

Example of usage:

```css
.upload-image {
    width: 100%;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: final-column;
}
```

Comment: It's probably a `custom-ident` as described on the linked page, not a value. If you can show more of the CSS we could now for sure.

Comment: You can name grid areas whatever you want, and that's probably what this is; someone named a grid area "final-column".

Comment: The last column is `-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think 'final-column' exists as a setting for grid-column-end.

In fact, if you put any old rubbish for that value you seem to get the image extending to the last column.

Try this snippet for example:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'A B C';
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: rubbish;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200">
</div>
```